How to optimize a python multithreading script that processes hashes?
I am working on a Python script that checks whether a hashed document number matches any document number in a large list of records stored in a MySQL database. To improve performance, I use the multiprocessing library to parallelize the processing across multiple chunks of the document list.
My main issue is achieving even lower processing times. After experimenting, I found that splitting the documents into 6 chunks and using 6 processes yields the best performance. However, I am unsure how to optimize this further.
For context, I am running this script on a VPS with 4 vCPUs and 8 GB of RAM. My database query retrieves at least 580 records, and in the worst case, the process can take 40 seconds. Finally, the documents have been hashed with bcrypt using 12 rounds.
import bcrypt
import mysql.connector
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import time
import sys
import os

MAX_WORKERS = 6
MAX_CHUNKS = 6

load_dotenv()

DB_HOST = os.getenv("ENTRIES_HOST")
DB_DATABASE = os.getenv("ENTRIES_DATABASE")
DB_USERNAME = os.getenv("ENTRIES_USERNAME")
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("ENTRIES_PASSWORD")
DB_PORT = os.getenv("ENTRIES_PORT")

def get_documents():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        database=DB_DATABASE,
        user=DB_USERNAME,
        password=DB_PASSWORD,
        port=DB_PORT
    )
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT nro_document FROM family_and_friends WHERE deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY id ASC;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    documents = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return documents

def verify_password(stored_hash, password_to_verify):
    return bcrypt.checkpw(password_to_verify.encode('utf-8'), stored_hash)

def process_chunk(chunk, stored_hash, found_flag):
    for document in chunk:
        if found_flag["found"]:
            break
        if verify_password(stored_hash, document):
            found_flag["found"] = True
            return document
    return None

def chunk_documents(documents, num_chunks):
    length = len(documents)
    chunk_size = (length + num_chunks - 1) // num_chunks
    return [documents[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, length, chunk_size)]

def main(stored_hash):
    documents = get_documents()
    start_time = time.time()

    with Manager() as manager:
        found_flag = manager.dict({"found": False})
        chunks = chunk_documents(documents, MAX_CHUNKS)

        with Pool(processes=MAX_WORKERS) as pool:
            results = [
                pool.apply_async(process_chunk, args=(chunk, stored_hash, found_flag))
                for chunk in chunks
            ]
            for result in results:
                output = result.get()
                if output is not None:
                    pool.terminate()
                    end_time = time.time()
                    return output

    end_time = time.time()
    return ''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("")
        sys.exit(-1)

    stored_hash = bytes(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8')
    result = main(stored_hash)
    print(result)
    sys.exit(1)


580 records or 580 thousands of records? oO

Just 580 records in my bd

If you have 4 vCPUs, it may not be a great idea to have MAX_WORKERS == 6. Also, just as an aside, sys.exit(1) implies an error

I tested  many conbinations, and i tried 4 workers but i dont know why i get a better performance with 6 workers

@beker32, basically your task is to extract 1 value from each of 580 entries, calculate it's hash and (if it matches input) return original value of the field. I don't quite understand what in this task is so resource consuming that you went so far with multiprocessing. It should take milliseconds if my understanding is correct.

This process was created to read a hash stored on an NFC band. This hash corresponds to the hash of the user's document number. They used bcrypt with 12 rounds to hash these document numbers. My task is to find the document number in my database associated with each hash that arrives as a parameter, but I can't make it work efficiently.

@beker32, have you tried to simplify your code to absolute essentials and benchmark it? Smth like this. How many seconds does it take?

Testing on MacOS (Apple M2), Python 3.13.1, bcrypt 4.2.1 reveals that bcrypt.checkpw() is slow. Average duration is ~0.27s. Therefore, sequential processing of 580 "records" would take ~160s. It follows that multiprocessing could help if implemented correctly. In testing (8 CPUs), 580 invocations of bcrypt.checkpw() can be achieved in ~22s overall using optimal multiprocessing techniques.

It appears that bcrypt.checkpw() is rather slow. It is CPU intensive and therefore multiprocessing makes sense.
When constructing a multiprocessing pool the default size will be equal to the number of available CPUs (os.process_cpu_count()). You may not want to use all CPUs.
Ignoring the acquisition of data from a database (because it's not really relevant to the issue at hand) here's a proof of how slow bcrypt.checkpw() is on my platform.
from bcrypt import hashpw, checkpw, gensalt
from time import time, perf_counter
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import AsyncResult
from itertools import repeat
from os import process_cpu_count
from sys import stderr

N = 580

def process(t: tuple[bytes, bytes]) -> float:
    start = perf_counter()
    if not checkpw(*t):
        print("Check failed!!", file=stderr)
    return perf_counter() - start

def main() -> None:
    password: bytes = b"MyWeakPassw0rd"
    nprocs = max((process_cpu_count() or 2) - 1, 1)
    print(f"{nprocs=}")
    with Pool(nprocs) as pool:
        args = password, hashpw(password, gensalt())
        result: AsyncResult = pool.map_async(process, repeat(args, N))
        average_time: float = sum(result.get()) / N
        print(f"{average_time=:.4f}s")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time()
    main()
    total_duration = time() - start
    print(f"{total_duration=:.4f}s")

Output:
nprocs=7
average_time=0.2772s
total_duration=23.6048s

Platform:
MacOS 15.2
Python 3.13.1
bcrypt 4.2.1
Apple M2 (8 CPU equivalent)

